# Finding common elements among all lines of a text file

Tags: awk

I have a text file like:

```
a b c d e
b c e
d f g e h c
```

I am looking for a simple AWK which can output the common elements among all lines ignoring their first element. The desired output is:

```
c e
```

or

```
e c
```

Comment: What if line 2 contained "d"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) common[$i]; next }
{
    for (c in common) {
        present = 0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i == c) {
                present = 1
            }
        }
        if (!present) {
            delete common[c]
        }
    }
}
END {
    i=0
    for (c in common) {
        printf "%s%s", (++i>1?OFS:""), c
    }
    print ""
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
c e
```

If you really want to skip the first char on each line, just change the 2 `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)` loops to start at 2 instead of 1.

Although the above was accepted I actually prefer @jaypal's approach (but not his choice of tool :-) ), so here's the awk equivalent:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ delete seen; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!seen[$i]++) count[$i]++ }
END {
    i=0
    for (c in count)
        if (count[c] == NR)
            printf "%s%s", (++i>1?OFS:""), c
    print ""
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
c e
```

If your awk doesn't support `delete seen`, change it to `split("",seen)`.

Answer (score 3):

`perl` to the rescue:

```
perl -lane '
    my %seen;
    map { $total{$F[$_]}++ unless $seen{$F[$_]}++ } 1 .. $#F; 
}{ 
    print join " ", grep { $total{$_} == $. } keys %total
' file
e c
```

Keep a rolling `%total` hash which will increment the elements only if they are unique for every line. `%seen` is a hash that helps keep track of those elements. Hence we use `my` declaration to reset it for every line.

In the `END` block we just `grep` those elements whose value meets the total number of lines as that would mean they were seen on every line.

The command line options are:

- `-l`: Chomps the newline and places it back during `print`.
- `-a`: Splits the line on whitespace and loads an array `@F` with those values.
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>) { .. }` loop to process every line.
- `-e`: Executes the code block thats follows in quotes.

Comment: +1 Nice! Approach stolen and added in awk to my answer. If you want to steal it back and add the awk equivalent to yours, feel free and I'll remove it from mine.

Comment: @EdMorton Even if I try, I cannot make it as prettier as yours! `:)` Duly upvoted!

Comment: It's considered bad form in perl to throw away the result of a grep or a map. You might consider `for (1..$#F) {$total{$F[$_]}++ unless $seen{$F[$_]}++}`

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah, I just wanted to keep it all in one-line for the one-liner solution, but point duly noted.

Comment: Well, my suggestion is one line. If you want `for` to be a statement modifier: `do {$total{$F[$_]}++ unless $seen{$F[$_]}++} for 1 .. $#F;`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, yeah I meant it in the form of statement modifier. Wasn't sure if you had indeed squeezed the `for` loop to one line or the comments made it like that. The `do { .. }` block looks good. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

Another perl approach:

```
perl -lane '
    if ($. == 1) { %intersect = map {$_ => 1} @F; next } 
    %intersect =  map {$_ => 1} grep {$intersect{$_}} @F; 
    END {print join " ", keys %intersect}
' file
```

Results will not be in any particular order.